# Conflict between Chrome and Hyper-V default switch

Tags: networking, windows-10, google-chrome, hyper-v

I have a strange problem: for the long time I have received error ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED in Chrome and Chrome-based browsers (e.g. Opera). At the beginning I suspected Bitdefender firewall and VirtualBox private network adapters. Finally I have figured out that the source of the problem is a new "Default Switch" feature in Windows10 1709. This switch is visible in Network Connections as Unindentified Network and is a cause of trouble. When I disable this switch network adapter the error dissapears.
What is the problem?

1. The Default Switch is enabled even if hypervisor is disabled at boot
   (BCD setting: hypervisorlaunchtype off).
2. When I remove adapter connected to Default Switch, it is recreated at the next boot.
3. If I disable this adapter, Windows10 creates another "Default Switch".

I teach different courses about network/Windows/Linux technologies so uinstalling Hyper-V nor VirtualBox is not an option.

Is it possible to configure Windows10 networking to prevent this problem?

My initial idea to solve this problem is to create PS script that runs at logon and logoff disabling/enabling DefaultSwitch adapter. So far I am not able to discover the Hyper-V hypervisor state (on/off). PS cmdlet **Get-WindowsOptionalFeature Hyper-v -online** informs only that Hyper-V is enabled or disabled, but not about its current state (on/off).

Comment: It shouldn't appear as Unidentified Network. Try to remove the Hyper-V feature, reboot, re-enable and reboot.

Comment: It did not resolve problem. I uninstalled antyvirus, reboot, hyper-v, reboot twice, installed hyper-v, reboot , installed, result is the same.

Maybe shoud I clear Hyper-V configuration the other way?

@harrymc - what is the state/configuration of your default switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally discovered that there is a bug in Windows 10.

If you had configured NAT in Hyper-V with *-NetNat cmdlet before you installed Windows10 1709 (with new DefaultSwitch feature),  your configuration of DefaultSwitch will be broken.

Advices given by MS staff on MS support forums are useless, as disabling and enabling Hyper-V feature (with multiple reboots in between) does not reset Hyper-V configuration. It is also not possible to configure DefaultSwitch manually.

15 Nov '18 Update:

I have found blog entry: [ https://mikefrobbins.com/2018/11/08/managing-the-hyper-v-default-switch-in-windows-10-version-1709-and-higher-with-powershell/#comment-39379 ] . Author suggests setting high metric on both IPv4 and IPv6 protocols of DefaultSwitch adapter:

```
Get-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias 'vEthernet (Default Switch)' | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 5000 -PassThru
```

It does not resolve problem (DefaultSwitch still does not work), however I can use browsers without ERR_NETWORK_CHANGE errors.

As no one in Microsoft knows how to repair their DefaultSwitch, probably the only complete solution is to make a clean install of 1809.